# How can I connect to Documentum with Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime using C# without the app.config for the ModuleInfo tags?

Tags: c#, .net, documentum, documentum6.5

Sample code using the app.config:

```
ContextFactory contextFactory = ContextFactory.Instance;
IServiceContext serviceContext = contextFactory.NewContext();
```

app.config section I'd like to set in code instead of having the API read it directly.

```
<Emc.Documentum>
    <FS>
      <ConfigObject type="Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.Impl.Configuration.ConfigObject, Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime"
       defaultModuleName="core" registryProviderModuleName="core" requireSignedUcfJars="true">
        <ModuleInfo name="core" protocol="http" host="documentum.current.dev" port="9080" contextRoot="services"/>
        <ModuleInfo name="search" protocol="http" host="documentum.current.dev" port="9080" contextRoot="services"/>
        <ModuleInfo name="bpm" protocol="http" host="documentum.current.dev" port="9080" contextRoot="services"/>
        <ModuleInfo name="collaboration" protocol="http" host="documentum.current.dev" port="9080" contextRoot="services" />
      </ConfigObject>
    </FS>
</Emc.Documentum>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may find your answer in the Documentum Developer Community:

https://community.emc.com/search.jspa?peopleEnabled=true&userID=&containerType=14&container=2013&spotlight=false&q=emc.documentum.fs.runtime*

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find an article on this that should enable us to configure what we need by manually editing the AppConfig singleton class properties.   https://community.emc.com/message/454938#454938